# How to display SQL Timings with Mini-Profiler 1.9.1 from background threads

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, mvc-mini-profiler, entity-framework-4.3

I'm trying to display the SQL timings from queries that are running on background threads with Entity Framework 4.3 Code first and MVC 4.  Another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341269/getting-mvc-mini-profiler-timings-into-async-tasks/8574227) mentions a good way to do this, but I don't think this approach works for Code First because the SqlTimings list ends up with no items in it.

I can't call `MiniProfilerEF.Initialize()` more than once and `Clone()` does not work, so I'm not sure what else to do.  Anyone have any good ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's enough information to resolve your issue, but have you tried looking into [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757659/mvcminiprofiler-on-ef-4-1-code-first-project-doesnt-profile-sql/6800657#6800657) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550046/using-mvc-mini-profiler-database-profiling-with-entity-framework-code-first)?

Comment: No, since those are not referring to EF Code First.